# datatables columns.data mathematical calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm building a datatables table, and I'd like to perform a calculation in one of my cells - I couldn't find anything on the datatables website that showed how to do this:

Here's my code:

```
// "calculation" should equal "data 8" divided by "data 9"

$('#qtw-graph-table2').DataTable( {
  data: dataParse,
  columns: [            
    { data: 8, title: "A"},
    { data: 9, title: "B"},                    
    { data: calculation, title: "C"}
  ]
});
```

I've tried creating a variable, and using that variable to populate the 3rd column:

`var calculation = dataParse[8] / dataParse[9]`  but it causes the table to fail, which makes sense because `data:` will be looking to load `dataParse[calculation]`, which a.) doesn't exist, and b.) is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to pass `null` as the value for data (see [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data)), then add a [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function

```
$('#qtw-graph-table2').DataTable({
    data: dataParse,
    columns: [            
        { data: 8, title: "A"},
        { data: 9, title: "B"},                    
        { 
            data: null, 
            title: "C", 
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                return data[8] / data[9];
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working fully - when I add `console.log(data[8]) and 9` above the `return...` line,  I get the correct values, so the data is being passed correctly, but I'm seeing `NaN` in my table....

Comment: @BrianPowell What values are they? The division symbol should automatically convert strings to numbers. It sounds like one of your values isn't a valid number.

Comment: stupid me - they're not integers, they're strings with a `$` in them......   I'll fix that, then your solution will work.  Thanks so much!